# Как работать со вложенностями в pydantic?

Tags: python, json, валидация, pydantic, validate

Я проводила тест данного JSON https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 и у меня вылезает данная ошибка:(IndexError: tuple index out of range)[image: ошибка: IndexError: tuple index out of range]

Я искала решение, задавала кучу вопросов, но так и не смогла решить эту проблему, сейчас я покажу свой код.

Составленная мной pydantic модель:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Suport(BaseModel):
    url: str
    text: str


class Users(BaseModel):
    id: int
    email: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    avatar: str


class Post(BaseModel):
    page: int
    per_page: int
    total: int
    total_pages: int
    data: list[Users]
    support: dict[Suport]
```

Класс с валидацией и проверкой статуса кода:

```
import global_enus
from post import Post
from pydantic import parse_obj_as

class Responce:
    def __init__(self, responce):
        self.responce = responce
        self.responce_json = responce.json()
        self.responce_status = responce.status_code

    def validate(self):
        if isinstance (self.responce_json, list):
            parse_obj_as(list[Post], self.responce_json)
        else:
            parse_obj_as(list[Post], self.responce_json)
        return self

    def assert_status_code(self, status_code):
        if isinstance(self.responce_status, list):
            assert status_code in self.responce_status, global_enus.error_message.WRONG_CODE
        else:
            assert status_code == self.responce_status, global_enus.error_message.WRONG_CODE
```

Мой мейн файл, в котором и происходит тест:

```
import requests
from responce_classes import Responce
from configuration import SERVICE_URL

def test_getting_post():
   r = requests.get(url=SERVICE_URL)
   responce = Responce(r)
   responce.assert_status_code(200)
   responce.validate()
```

Ошибка возникает именно при валидации, то есть, когда я отрабатываю тест только на проверку статус кода он всё отрабатывает.
Суть вопроса в следующем: как в pydantic работать с ситуацией когда значение это словарь или другой список?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с данной проблемой, а то на всём белом свете я так и не нашла ответа.

Comment: `dict[Suport]` - некорректная аннотация

Comment: А судя по примеру приведённого json, здесь видимо должно быть просто `Suport`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @andreymal даже если изменить dict[Suport] на Suport получаю ошибку: 

   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ParsingModel[list[post.Post]]
   __root__
     value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

Comment: @KANA показанный вами пример json очевидно не является списком, а вы почему-то пытаетесь парсить его как список, отсюда и логичная ошибка

Comment: @andreymal Так в этом то и вопрос. Как работать со вложенностями в pydantic? У нас есть dict один из ключей которого 'data' его значение это вложенный list. Но так же есть support у него значение является dict. Как верно описать такую модель. Не могли бы вы написать правильную версию кода?

Comment: Если вы хотите распарсить весь этот responce_json целиком как объект Post, то, очевидно, нужно для начала хотя бы избавиться от абсолютно ненужного списка, заменив `list[Post]` на просто `Post`. А уже потом дальше изучать следующие ошибки, если они будут

Comment: @andreymal извините, но это никак не решает проблему и не отвечает на поставленный мною вопрос)
А косательно не нужного list так было написано в официальной документации цитирую код: "
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    count: int
    size: Optional[float] = None


class Bar(BaseModel):
    apple = 'x'
    banana = 'y'


class Spam(BaseModel):
    foo: Foo
    bars: List[Bar]
"

Comment: @andreymal Я принимаю данное утверждение. Но если вы знаете как сделать правильно, не могли бы вы показать как описать данную модель верно в виде кода. :)

Comment: После исправления двух ранее упомянутых мной ошибок вся связанная с pydantic часть кода начинает успешно работать и в итоге тест успешно проходит

Comment: @andreymal Извините, но даже после замены  data: list[Users] и support: dict[Suport] на  data: Users и support: Suport. 
Тест все равно не проходит, и я получаю все ту же ошибку 
"   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ParsingModel[list[post.Post]]
   __root__
     value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list) "

Comment: @andreymal ой боже, извините пожалуйста, я после нескольких часов работы с этим кодом совсем запуталась и изменяла не то, да, вы были абсолютно правы, после исправления этих строчек у меня всё проходит и если нужно, проваливается. Спасибо большое и извините пожалуйста. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговым решением на мой вопрос было:

Заменить в коде support: dict[Suport] на support: Suport
И изменить list[Post] на просто Post.

Большое спасибо за помощь: @andreymal